# Docker remove container with changes

Tags: docker

How can I remove a container without removing all the changes that have been made in this container?

I already used:

Stop all running containers: `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`

Delete all stopped containers: `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a docker image from your container with `docker commit`.
This image can be used to start up new containers or can be pushed to a docker repository for later use.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Answer (score 0):

You don’t.  Anything you change in a Docker container will be lost as soon as the container is deleted.  Also, you need to routinely delete containers to change options like the base image (if there’s some security patch you need), networking options, or environment variables.

The standard pattern for this involves two things:

1. Don’t install software or make other configuration changes inside a running container.  Instead, write a `Dockerfile` that does that work for you, check it into source control, and use `docker build` to build an image from it.  (If you get something wrong, you can easily fix it and re-run it; if you need to update something in six months you have a written record of what you did.)
2. If your container does need some persistent state, start it with `docker run -v` or a similar option to mount a host directory or named volume into the container.  Data stored there will outlive the container.

In theory `docker commit` can turn a container into an image, but using it really isn’t a best practice.  Images you build this way can’t be recreated or updated (again, imagine a critical security fix in the underlying base image).  In some cases a committed container won’t even have the data you want to save (for example you can’t usefully commit a MySQL or PostgreSQL container).